# NPE when scrolling listview containing radiogroups

Tags: android, android-listview, android-radiogroup

I have a following problem. I have a `ListView` which displays a test. In each `ListView` row there is a question and a `RadioGroup` with answers. THe problem I am experiencing is that I am getting this error everytime when I scroll the `ListView` down and I don't know the cause of such behaviour:

LogCat:

```
02-05 11:22:56.712  27296-27296/com.fragon.testjson E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fragon.testjson, PID: 27296
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.fragon.testjson.ListAdapter.getView(ListAdapter.java:38)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:655)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5143)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3243)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3587)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3431)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7837)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1945)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2075)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1522)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2023)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8017)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3966)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3845)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3405)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3455)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3424)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3531)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3432)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3588)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3405)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3455)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3424)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3432)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3405)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5554)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5534)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5505)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5634)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5607)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5653)
            at andr
```

My ListAdapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Question> {


    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Question> questions) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, questions);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        final Question question = getItem(position);
        TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_id);
        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_text);
        id.setText(Integer.toString(question.getId()));
        text.setText(question.getName());

        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
        rg.removeAllViews();//Line 38. Whithout his line I also get the same error.
        rg.setId(position);
        int i = 0;
        for (String qA : question.answers) {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(getContext());
            rb.setText(qA.toString());
            rg.addView(rb);
            rb.setId(i);
            i++;
        }

        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            question.setUserAnswer(checkedId);
            Log.d("User answer", Integer.toString(checkedId));
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: The radioGroup 'rg' seems to be null. Are you sure the R.layout.list_item contains a View with id 'R.id.question'?

Comment: Can you mark line 38 in ListAdapter.java?

Comment: @Herrmann Yes, I am sure. The ListView displays fine. I get this error only when scrolling down the list.

Comment: @skywall It is marked

Comment: Can you post `R.layout.list_item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `rg.setId(position);` is changing the `RadioGroup`'s ID to something other than `R.id.question`, so when then `View` gets recycled - i.e., when you scroll - `findViewById(R.id.question)` is returning null.

If you need to cache the position, you could use the `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods instead. You could also just cache the `Question` object instead. For example:

```
//rg.setId(position);
rg.setTag(question);
...
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
    {
        Question q = (Question) group.getTag();
        q.setUserAnswer(checkedId);
        Log.d("User answer", Integer.toString(checkedId));
    }
});
```

You could also define just one `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener` instead of creating a new one for each group.

```
//rg.setId(position);
rg.setTag(question);
...
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);
...
...
private RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener checkListener =
    new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
        {
            Question q = (Question) group.getTag();
            q.setUserAnswer(checkedId);
            Log.d("User answer", Integer.toString(checkedId));
        }
    };
```

Comment: Could you please give me some hints on how to fix it?

Comment: @6franek I was editing my answer to suggest using the RadioGroup's tag instead. But from the code you've posted, it doesn't look like you're using the RadioGroup's ID anyway, so you could just remove that line.

Comment: Actually, you probably will need to cache the position, so ignore my comment about removing it, and change it to `setTag()`, which you could use to cache the position `int`, or the `Question` object itself.

Comment: @6franek I updated my answer again to provide an example. Lemme know if you've any problems.

Comment: Your solution works. THe problem I have now is that the selection is missed when the LIstView element is outside the visible part of the screen.

Comment: When I remove this line: `rg.removeAllViews()` what the user answer is presereved, but more RadioButtons are added every time when List element is not visible.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a second to figure out what you meant. After you've recreated the RadioButtons in `getView()`, you'll have to set the one that was selected for that question, by checking, for example, `question.getUserAnswer()`.

Answer (score 0):

You change the ID of the RadioGroup: `rg.setId(position);`

ListView reuses the views if you scroll down. Because you changed the ID `findViewById()` does return `null`.

**Solution**:

1. Implement a custom `OnCheckedChangeListener` that knows its position in the `ListView`.

   ```
   private static class QuestionCheckedListener implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{

   private final int mPosition;

   QuestionCheckedListener(int position){
       mPosition = position;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
       question.setUserAnswer(mPosition);
       Log.d("User answer", Integer.toString(checkedId));
   }
   ```

   }
2. Instantiate it in `getView()`:

   ```
   rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new QuestionCheckedListener(position));
   ```
3. And do not forget to remove all `setId(i)` calls

Comment: Could you please give me some hints on how to fix it?

Comment: I don't think that's gonna work as the OP intends. It looks like the `setUserAnswer()` method is meant to take the ID of the selected RadioButton in the group, not the list position.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, indeed. seUserAnswer() takes the ID of the selected RadioButton in the group.

Comment: How can that work? If the ID of the RadioGroup is not changed manually it does not change at all. All RadioGroups do have the same ID, because they are inflated from the same layout.